# Wyvern and Channel Forms

Tags: assets, safecracker, rte, wyvern

I've been looking into creating a front-end client dashboard using wyvern, assets and of course channel forms.  I have played with many configurations to get the 'dashboard' working.  Specifically, everything is fine except for the channel fields that are Wyvern, [image: Wyvern Fields] just show up on the dashboard as a normal 'textarea' field in the likes of the normal rich-text editor.  [image: wyvern field on front end showing as normal editor]  while in the EE control panel it shows Wyvern tools [image: EE Control Panel]

The 'dashboard' template follows something like :

```
              {exp:channel:form channel="page" entry_id="{segment_4}" json="yes" include_jquery="yes"rte_selector=".ee-rte" toolset_id="2"}

<div class="col-lg-12">

  <div class="form-element-wrapper">
    <label for="about">About</label>
    <textarea id="about" name="about" rows="12" class="ee-rte">{about}</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-element-wrapper">
    <label for="body">Body</label>
    <textarea id="body" name="body" rows="12" class="ee-rte">{body}</textarea>
  </div>

  ...etc
```

I know there's the class="ee-rte" and the rte_selector=".ee-rte" but does this affect the Wyvern fields and possibly why I can't get Wyvern to show up in the 'dashboard' fields?

or maybe it's the:

```
    <textarea id="about" name="about" rows="12" class="ee-rte">{about}</textarea>
```

area because that's calling the "textarea", but then how do you call in Wyvern?

Any help or suggestions you may have would be awesome.  I know there has to be a simple solution that I'm just completely overlooking.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's how this was fixed:

```
 {exp:channel:form channel="your_channel"}
    <div class="form-element-wrapper" id="custom-field-container">
       <label for="custom_field">Custom Field Label</label>
          {field:custom_field}
    </div>
 etc
 etc
 {/exp:channel:form}
```

:-)